# Firebug: nested <strong> tags

Tags: html, firefox-addon, firebug

Here's the screenshot of my firebug installed in updated firefox. I've noticed that the firebug shows hidden nested  tag in the html tab. I don't know what causes this to happen...[image]

Anyone?..Please help....Thanks...

And here's the html mark-up..[image]

Comment: Please post the markup to ensure you don't have ... nested strong tags

Comment: What's the actual HTML source look like?  I'm guessing Firebug is misinterpreting some invalid markup.

Comment: @Trez: don't post the markup as shown by Firebug — post the markup as you coded in your editor for this page.

Comment: ... and post the markup as text in your question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @Tim Goodman Firebug does not interpret markup so it cannot mis-interpret markup. Firebug shows you what Firefox has stored in the browser for your input.

Comment: @johnjbarton: Perhaps then I should say *Firefox* is misinterpreting it.  I use Firebug every day, but I can't say I'm terribly familiar with how it works "under the hood".  But *something* is parsing the HTML before it's shown by Firebug, and in this case, I guess, parsing it incorrectly.  (I.e., not in the way intended by whomever wrote the HTML.)  Assuming they didn't really write 20 consecutive strong tags.

Comment: Hey guys...as @meder suggestion... i tried to validate it using W3C validator and finally the <strong> tags reduced as the error get fixed...However, thank you for your time to share some posibilities on what causes the problem. More power to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have invalid markup which may include extraneous opening tags or extraneous closing tags. Pay attention to inline elements that may contain block levels, which isn't allowed.

I would [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) because the `width` attribute is an indication that the markup isn't the best it could be.

Comment: the add-on html validator of firefox doesn't show any warning or error on html...

Comment: Please validate using the real service and tell us if there are warnings/errors. Otherwise you're wasting time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion... I tried to validate in W3C validator and i got some errors..now i'm fixing it..and have a good news <strong> tags reduced as the errors get corrected. Thank you...